# vbScript - Arrays

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I am fairly new in vbScript and was wondering if anyone could please advise:

I am trying to loop for a single value in an array. See the following:

```
Dim reportesTA(3)
reportesTA(0) = "REPORT1"
reportesTA(1) = "REPORT2"
reportesTA(2) = "REPORT3"
```

I wrote a Sub procedure as follow:

```
Sub REPORTE1()
    For Each i=0 In reportesTA
        posicionarCursor() ''This is another sub
        commKeys reportesTA(0)
    Next
End Sub
```

It won't work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The other way I
though to do this would be:

```
For i=0 to 0
    posicionarCursor() ''This is another sub
    commKeys reportesTA(0)
Next
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't work`?

Comment: It says that an "In" is expected in the line of "For Each i=0 In reportesTA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two syntax to loop through an array:

```
For Each i In reportesTA
' your code here
next
```

or this one:

```
for i=0 to ubound(reportesTA)
' your code here
next
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of an array is given by the zero-based last valid index, not the number of elements; so

```
>> Dim rTA(2) ' 3 elms from 0 to 2
>> rTA(0) = "1"
>> rTA(1) = "2"
>> rTA(2) = "3"
```

To loop over an array, either use a count/index loop:

```
>> For i = LBound(rTA) To UBound(rTA)
>>     WScript.Echo i, rTA(i)
>> Next
>>
0 1
1 2
2 3
```

and access the elements via array(index), or a For Each loop

```
>> For Each r In rTA
>>     WScript.Echo r
>> Next
1
2
3
```

giving you access to (a copy of) each element without having to use an index.

Comment: I want to write a sub procedure for each element in the array. So it would be something like "For Each 0 in rTA...do code...Next"? This would be for rta(0)

Comment: The For Each sample **calls** a Sub (WScript.Echo) for each element of rTA.